# Sitecore Experience editor error in xm cloud partial design

Tags: sitecore, experience-editor

Looking for help on solving Experience editor error in xm cloud., We are using xm cloud + next js to build a website. Experience editor is not opening to do edits for partial design, whereas it is opening at the home page level, which again refers to partial design via page design selected.

Error: Connection to your rendering host failed with the following error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

the rendering host settings and reference updates in the site setting level were added as expected. (We tried deleting the default and checked once it auto-created)

Even an empty / newly created partial design gives the same error when opening in the experience editor

Used https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head-staging as a base solution to set up the instance.

We saw an error like this in the rendering container - processTicksAndRejections

And following the “https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/21/sitecore-headless-development/troubleshooting-jss-next-js-apps.html” and no luck

Graph QL, Layout service gives output JSON for the partial design as expected.

We tried recreating the new environment using the same branch and still issue exists

Please provide input for resolving this issue.

Comment: there is a react component issue in the head app. Investigating the same.

Comment: Usually 500 errors : "Connection to your rendering host failed with the following error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error" are the issues inside nextjs app.
If you are using the docker for your rendering host check the docker logs for your rendering host when you are opening the partial design.